# Special case in a method of a generic class c#

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to make a method from a generic class behave complety different for a specific type?

```
class MyClass<T> {
    public void myMethod(T t) { // Do something }

    // something for myMethod(int t) { // DO something special }
}
```

In such a way that allows me to call `(new MyClass<String>()).myMethod(myString)` which will do  something and also call `(new MyClass<int>()).myMethod(myInt)`which will do something special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would be better just using overloads for that, rather than generics.

For example:

```
public void myMethod(int t)
{
}

public void myMethod(string t)
{
}
```

You *can* do type checking in generics, but it's not the best practice.

Based on your edit and dicussion, I believe this is what you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntClass c1 = new IntClass();
        c1.MyMethod(12);

        BaseClass<string> c2 = new BaseClass<string>();
        c2.MyMethod("hello world");
    }
}

class BaseClass<T>
{
    public virtual void MyMethod(T t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Param: {0}", t));
    }
}

class IntClass : BaseClass<int>
{
    public override void MyMethod(int myVar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Param: int"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changued the question because the class is generic, the method is not. Does this aproach still work?

Comment: Yes, because regardless of the type you pass to the class, you're still using the relevant overload.  That is, it's the same class, regardless of which type you pass to it.

Comment: But that introduces a new method that i dont want. I mean, if I have `MyClass<String> c` i dont want people to be able to call `c.mymethod(myInt)`

Comment: In that case, I would suggest having two classes, rather than tying to use the same class for obviously different purposes.

Comment: The class has 8 methods which are similar, and only this is different. It seems very ugly to me to copy all those methods

Comment: No - don't copy them.  Either use a base or helper class to collect common functionality, and then just expose a facade for the interface

Comment: Your `IntClass` hides a method that it acquires from its base class, by introducing another method. This can be confusing. Consider making the method `virtual` in the base, and `override` in the special class.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and have both overloads,

```
public void myMethod(T t) { ... }
```

and

```
public void myMethod(int t) { ... }
```

Both methods are non-generic, but one uses the `T` of the containing class.

If you construct

```
MyClass<int>
```

the signatures of the two methods wil **unite**. Is the what you fear?

The call `(new MyClass<int>()).myMethod(42);` goes to the second overload.

---

I might have misunderstood your question. Do you want only one method? What exactly do you want to do special in the case of `int`. You *can* make code like:

```
public void myMethod(T t)
{
  // do something

  if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
  {
    // special case
    // if you need t as an int, you can use the ugly (int)(object)t
  }

}
```

You can also consider writing a specific class for the `int` case. That class may derive from the general class (your method may be made `virtual`).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a non-generic overload of the method:

```
public void myMethod(int t) { // Special case for integer argument }
public void myMethod<T>(T t) { // Generic method for everything else }
```

Comment: I have changued the question because the class is generic, the method is not. Does this aproach still work?. Also, that introduces a new method that i dont want. I mean, if I have `MyClass<String> c` i dont want people to be able to call `c.mymethod(myInt)`

Comment: @Trollkemada: No, because you can call `MyClass<string>.myMethod(3)` which is obviously wrong. C# does not support specialization of generic classes, so either you have to go back to the drawing board or the method has to be generic. Of course you could also do `if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))`.